# How to do a sub-query in SQL

Tags: sql

My table looks something like this:

[image: SQL TABLE]

I want to retrieve all the PractitionerIdFK if they have SpecialityIdFK = 1 AND SpecialityIdFK= 2. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT PractitionerSpecialities.PractitionerIdFK
FROM PractitionerSpecialities
WHERE PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK IN (
        SELECT PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK
        FROM PractitionerSpecialities
        WHERE PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK = 1
            AND PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK = 2
        )
```

Comment: Try `or` instead of `and` in your `where` clause since the SpecialityIdFK can't be both 1 and 2 at the same time.  You could also do `where PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK IN (1, 2)`

Comment: The subquery is unnecessary, Just change your `IN` expression as @MarkMoretto describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT ps.PractitionerIdFK 
FROM PractitionerSpecialities ps
WHERE ps.SpecialityIdFK IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ps.PractitionerIdFK 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- the size of the comparison list
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates in `PractitionerSpecialities`.  If that is a possibility, then use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ps.SpecialityIdFK) = 2`.

Comment: ,In the question he\she doesn't ask about duplicate ,as per him he just want all PractitionerIdFK values for the SpecialityIdFK value 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by using **IN** and **BETWEEN** operator in SQL .

```
SELECT  PractitionerSpecialities.PractitionerIdFK 
FROM PractitionerSpecialities
WHERE PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK in (1,2)

-- You can BETWEEN Clause as well ..

SELECT  PractitionerSpecialities.PractitionerIdFK 
FROM PractitionerSpecialities
WHERE PractitionerSpecialities.SpecialityIdFK BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

In Sub query use OR operator instead of AND .

Comment: Maybe I am a little bit confused but what if
I want to return ONLY the PractitionerIdFK if they have SpecialityIdFK 1 and 3? I don't want to display users who have SpecialityIdFK 1 or 3 but instead return users who meet the criteria of having  SpecialityIdFK 1 and 3?

Comment: (1) I am baffled at what `BETWEEN` has to do with the question.  (2) An upvote?